# MySQL backup with CronJOb

Tags: cron, mysql, cpanel

I am trying to export MySQL data with CronJob in cPanel and I am adding bellow code into command line:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -u krystald_fred -p'tY$645=&nm' max_joomla > /home/max/db-backup.sql
```

After CronJob runs and when I check db-backup.sql file I am getting blank file with no data inside `.sql` file.

What's wrong with this command line. Can anyone guide me to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: try to execute it directly (not via the cronjob) and see what's the output / error message

Comment: Using a password that doesn't contain characters like `$` and `&` might help. Also, try adding `2>&1` to the end of the command line, then at least you'll be able to see what the error is

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info there. There could be many issues. Just run from command line with `-v` verbose flag and see. You might also need to connect via the 3306 port and specify hostname. It all depends on your installation.